# Discontinuities of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(nx)}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck trying to prove that the real valued function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(nx)}{n^2}$ (where $(nx)$ denotes the fractional part of $nx$) contains a  countable dense number of discontinities, but that $f$ is still Riemann-integrable on any bounded interval. This is what I have so far, any hints would much appreciated:

By definition, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $$f(x)=\sum\frac{(nx)}{n^2}=\sum\frac{nx-[nx]}{n^2}<\sum \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{(nx)}{n^2}$. By above, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}, f_n(x) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Consider some $x_1\in \mathbb{Q}$- we may write $x_1=\frac{p}{q}$ for integers $p,q$ and so it follows that $f_q(x_1)=0$. Since, $$f_q(t) \to z>0, \qquad as \qquad t\to x_1^-,$$  $f_q$ is discontinuous at $x_1$.

Since $f(x)=\sum f_n(x)$ and each $f_n$ is discontinuous for the set $S_n=\{x: x=\frac{p}{n}, p\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, does it immediately follow that $f$ is discontinuous for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, or do I need to show that $S=\{S_n\}$ is dense?

If we restrict our attention to the interval $I=[m,m+1],$ for some integer $m$, and if we can then show that for $x,y\in I$, if $$x<y \implies f(x)<f(y),$$ this would mean $f$ is monotonic and thus Riemann-integrabable on $I$. Could I then extend this argument to any bounded interval $[a,b]$, by partitioning it appropiately and summing the respective integrals?

Comment: Welcome to MSE..+1 upvote for presenting us your thoughts and attempts..good for you.:)